# Preenchimento do form com retorno de um json

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

Estou utilizando um webService (viaCep) para preenchimento automático do logradouro, para quando o usuário digitar um CEP. 
O webService me retorna um json com as informações do logradouro, e desse retorno preencho os *inputs* referente(Rua, cidade, etc..).

Quando digito manualmente as informações dos campos referente a endereço, consigo obter os mesmo na requisição.

Quando os campos são preenchidos com as informações do WebService, ao obter as requisição do *form*, os campos (Cidade, Estado, Rua, etc..) chegam *null*.

JavaScript que retorna o *json* do WebService:

```
function limpa_formulário_cep() {
   document.getElementById('endereco').value = ("");
   document.getElementById('bairro').value = ("");
   document.getElementById('cidade').value = ("");
   document.getElementById('estado').value = ("");
}

function meu_callback(conteudo) {
   if (!("erro" in conteudo)) {
      document.getElementById('endereco').value = (conteudo.logradouro);
      document.getElementById('bairro').value = (conteudo.bairro);
      document.getElementById('cidade').value = (conteudo.localidade);
      document.getElementById('estado').value = (conteudo.uf)
   }
    else {
       limpa_formulário_cep();
       alert("CEP não encontrado.");
   }
}

 function pesquisacep(valor) {

 var cep = valor.replace(/\D/g, '');

 if (cep != "") {
    var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;
    if (validacep.test(cep)) {
        document.getElementById('endereco').value = "...";
        document.getElementById('bairro').value = "...";
        document.getElementById('cidade').value = "...";
        document.getElementById('estado').value = "...";

        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/' + cep + '/json/?callback=meu_callback';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    } 
    else {
        limpa_formulário_cep();
        alert("Formato de CEP inválido.");
    }
} 
   else {
      limpa_formulário_cep();
   }
 };
```

*Form* que consulta e recebe o retorno do JS:

```
  <input name="cep" id="cep"  onblur="pesquisacep(this.value);" ng-model="contribuinte.cep" type="text"/>
  <input name="estado" id="estado"  ng-model="contribuinte.estado" charcase="uppercase" type="text"/>
  <input name="cidade" id="cidade" ng-model="contribuinte.cidade" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi você está utilizando AngularJS junto com o JavaScript puro, correto?

Comment: Isso, @CamiloSilva . Versão 1x.

Comment: Sim, meu controller recebe esse objeto 'contribuinte'.

Comment: Sinceramente não entendi o problema, achei o enunciado confuso.

Comment: Desculpe a sinceridade, mas recomendo ajustar esse português aí, pelo menos para mim a pergunta continua sem sentido. Você falou: "Nele preencho alguns inputs do meu formulário. Como por exemplo, retornou "Rio de Janeiro" e preenchi meu form o input do label 'Cidade'". Isso significa que ele retorna algo para você antes de você digitar???

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avaliando o código postado parece-me que você está fazendo mal uso ou subutilizando o AngularJS, perdendo assim as vantagens do framework. Exemplo disso está no código abaixo em que você abre mão de utilizar o recurso do `model`.

```
   document.getElementById('endereco').value = ("");
```

Assim como diversos frameworks atuais o Angularjs trabalha internamente com a ideia de ciclo de vida, o que torna mister seguir a filosofia adotada pelo mesmo. Abaixo segue um exemplo de como consumir a api que deseja no padrão adotado pelo framework:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('CepController', function($http) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.pesquisarCep = function() {

      var cepValido = /^[0-9]{5}[-]?[0-9]{3}$/.test(vm.cep);

      if (cepValido) {

        $http.get("https://viacep.com.br/ws/" + vm.cep + "/json/").then(
          function(response) {
            vm.endereco = response.data;
          },
          function(error) {
            if (error.status === 404) {
              alert('Cep não encontrado');
            }
          } //callback para tratameno de falhas
        );
      } else {
        alert('CEP inválido!');
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<h2>Via Cep</h2>

<form ng-app="app" ng-controller="CepController as vm">
  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.cep" />
  <button ng-click="vm.pesquisarCep()">Pesquisar</button>
  <hr>
  <table border>
    <tr style="background-color:aquamarine">
      <th>CEP</th>
      <th>Logradouro</th>
      <th>Complemento</th>
      <th>Bairro</th>
      <th>Localidade</th>
      <th>UF</th>
      <th>Unidade</th>
      <th>IBGE</th>
      <th>GIA</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="vm.endereco">
      <td>{{vm.endereco.cep}}</td>
      <td>{{vm.endereco.logradouro}}</td>
      <td>{{vm.endereco.complemento}}</td>
      <td>{{vm.endereco.bairro}}</td>
      <td>{{vm.endereco.localidade}}</td>
      <td>{{vm.endereco.uf}}</td>
      <td>{{vm.endereco.unidade}}</td>
      <td>{{vm.endereco.ibge}}</td>
      <td>{{vm.endereco.gia}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/devL9yp3GwZK0Ao2u8nI?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Se for utilizar `AngularJS`, utilize-o em sua totalidade. Evite misturar. A chamada com `jsonp` pode ser verificada como abaixo:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('appCep', [])
    .controller('CepController', CepController);

  CepController.$inject = ['$http'];

  function CepController($http) {
    const FORMATO = /^[0-9]{8}$/;
    var vm = this;
    vm.pesquisar = _pesquisar;

    _inicializar();

    function _inicializar() {
      vm.contribuinte = {};
      vm.mensagem = {};
      vm.mensagem.visivel = false;
      _limpar();
    }

    function _pesquisar() {
      var cep = vm.contribuinte.cep.replace(/\D/g, '');

      if (FORMATO.test(cep)) {
        $http.jsonp('https://viacep.com.br/ws/' + cep + '/json/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(_atribuir);
      } else {
        _limpar();
        vm.mensagem.visivel = true;
      }
    }

    function _atribuir(dados) {
      if (dados.erro) {
        _limpar();
        vm.mensagem.visivel = true;
      } else {
        vm.contribuinte.logradouro = dados.logradouro;
        vm.contribuinte.bairro = dados.bairro;
        vm.contribuinte.estado = dados.uf;
        vm.contribuinte.cidade = dados.localidade;

        vm.mensagem.visivel = false;
      }
    }

    function _limpar() {
      vm.contribuinte.logradouro = '...';
      vm.contribuinte.bairro = '...';
      vm.contribuinte.estado = '...';
      vm.contribuinte.cidade = '...';
    }
  };
})();
```

```css
div.vermelho {
  color: red;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="appCep">
  <div ng-controller="CepController as vm">
    <label>CEP:</label> <input name="cep" id="cep" ng-blur="vm.pesquisar()" ng-model="vm.contribuinte.cep" type="text" />
    <br>
    <label>Logradouro:</label> <input name="logradouro" id="logradouro" ng-model="vm.contribuinte.logradouro" charcase="uppercase" type="text" ng-disabled="true" />
    <br>
    <label>UF:</label> <input name="estado" id="estado" ng-model="vm.contribuinte.estado" charcase="uppercase" type="text" ng-disabled="true" />
    <br>
    <label>Bairro:</label> <input name="bairro" id="bairro" ng-model="vm.contribuinte.bairro" type="text" ng-disabled="true" />
    <br>
    <label>Cidade:</label> <input name="cidade" id="cidade" ng-model="vm.contribuinte.cidade" type="text" ng-disabled="true" />

    <div ng-show="vm.mensagem.visivel" class="vermelho">
      CEP ({{vm.contribuinte.cep}}) não encontrado!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

No exemplo acima criei o `Controller` `CepController` em que as variáveis e funções são agrupadas. A função `pesquisar` utiliza o `service` `$http` para realizar a chamada da `URL` e tratar o retorno. Note que não manipulei o `DOM` diretamente em momento algum, utilizando assim todo o potencial do framework.

Answer (score -1):

Primeiramente verifique se a linha

```
script.src = 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/' + cep + '/json/?callback=meu_callback';
```

está construindo a URL corretamente.
Após, creio que vale a pena utilizar as propriedades do Angular para vincular os elementos HTML com o seu script.

```
document.getElementById('endereco').value = "...";
document.getElementById('bairro').value = "...";
document.getElementById('cidade').value = "...";
document.getElementById('estado').value = "...";
```

Devem ser substituídas por

```
$scope.contribuinte.endereco = (conteudo.logradouro);
$scope.contribuinte.bairro = (conteudo.bairro);
$scope.contribuinte.cidade = (conteudo.localidade);
$scope.contribuinte.estado = (conteudo.uf);
```

Comment: Vc percebeu que está misturando sintaxe do angular em um arquivo javaScript nativo?

Comment: Sim, isso é possível contando que esse código esteja dentro do seu Controller